# Closed formula for series $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^i-y^i}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

What can be said about $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^i-y^i}$ (for $|x|>1$ and $|y|>1$ and $x\neq y$)?

Is there a kind of closed formula for this?

By comparing to the geometric series, this sum should be absolutely convergent since
$|x^i-y^i|\geq \left| |x|^i - |y|^i\right|=\left||x|-|y|\right|\cdot 
\left(|x|^{i-1} +|x|^{i-2} |y|+\ldots+|x||y|^{i-2}+|y|^{i-1}\right)\geq 
\left||x|-|y|\right|\cdot i \cdot q^{i-1}\geq \left||x|-|y|\right| q^{i-1}$

with $q=\operatorname{min}\{|x|,|y|\}>1$.

Comment: Wolfram alpha claims to solve the special case y=1: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum+1%2F%28x%5Ei-1%29+i+from+1+to+infinity

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4317994/442

Comment: @GeraldEdgar i think letting your $q^2$  here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/186303/is-this-infinite-series-related-to-some-well-known-special-functions/186315#186315   Equal the OP’s $\frac{y}{x}$ recasts their sum with theta functions (assuming your $a=1$ and your $x$ is the reciprocal of OP’s $a$)

Comment: The sum in my reference is $-\infty$ to $\infty$, not $1$ to $\infty$.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! It seems to me that the formulas in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/186303/is-this-infinite-series-related-to-some-well-known-special-functions/186315#186315 don't work for a=1. Since they run from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ they include n=0 and for a=1 the summand is not defined.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar: do you have a source (perhaps with proof) where I can look up these formulas?